# Adding Third Post Box Column: postbox-container-3

Tags: plugin-development

I've studied plugins that have postbox-container-1 and postbox-container-2 in use. The best implementation of post boxes I have seen is in [TablePress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/)

I had to adapt the approach used in TablePress for multiple views per WP admin page in CSV 2 POST as it as far more views. It all works fine. I can switch to a single column or two but I cannot add third.

None of TablePress views have three columns and I've not found a good plugin for example. I thought it would be as simple as copying the div for first and second columns but postbox-container-3 only creates an empty space that no boxes can be positioned within.

The Screen Options tab displays the 3rd radio so that is being selected.

What is the solution?

Is there any plugins using three columns of post boxes like on the dashboard?

```
<div id="poststuff">
    <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-<?php echo ( isset( $GLOBALS['screen_layout_columns'] ) && ( 2 == $GLOBALS['screen_layout_columns'] ) ) ? '2' : '1'; ?>">

        <div id="postbox-container-2" class="postbox-container">
        <?php
            $this->do_text_boxes( 'normal' );
            $this->do_meta_boxes( 'normal' );

            $this->do_text_boxes( 'additional' );
            $this->do_meta_boxes( 'additional' );

            // print all submit buttons
            $this->do_text_boxes( 'submit' );
        ?>
        </div>

        <div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container">
        <?php
        // print all boxes in the sidebar
            $this->do_text_boxes( 'side' );
            $this->do_meta_boxes( 'side' );
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

Comment: For the sake of readability, please properly format your code before adding it to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. There was a strange issue happening where it would allow me to format some of it but cut off 2-4 lines and treat it as normal text. Couldn't get it to treat the entire copy and paste as code. Normally I don't have issues like that.